# Image Tray creation using swing

Tags: java, image, performance, swing

i am creating an image tray using swing. what it does is finds all the image files in a folder or a drive and then adds these to the tray which is actually a JPanel. the code follows :

```
public void findAllPhotos(File f ) {
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if(file.isFile()) {
            String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            for(String s : extensions) {
                if(path.endsWith(s)) {
                     addImageToTray(file);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            findAllPhotos(file);
        }
     }
}
void addImageToTray(File fname) {
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fname);
        if(img == null) return;
        double width = 0, height = 0;
        if(iconView) {
            width = Math.min(img.getWidth(), iconWidth); 
            height = Math.min(img.getHeight(), iconHeight);
        }
        else {
            width = Math.min(img.getWidth(), tileWidth); 
            height = Math.min(img.getHeight(), tileHeight);
        }
        AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(width/img.getWidth(), (height/img.getHeight()))); 
        img = new AffineTransformOp(af, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR).filter(img, null);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        if(iconView) { 
            jl.setText("   " +fname.getName());
            jl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft JhengHei UI Light", 1, 11)); 
        }
        addActionListner(jl, fname.getAbsolutePath());
        jl.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        tray.add(jl);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "unknown problem, with tray creation!!!");
    }
}
```

My problem is that it is slow for large folders and while scanning drives.
Please suggest methods to improve the speed

Comment: Did you try to profile it?

Comment: No, i think that there are some high level optmizations that can be made before profiling.

Comment: `jl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft JhengHei UI Light", 1, 11));`  That will break on OS X & *nix.  If you intend to code only for Windows, look into .Net. `ImageIO.read(fname);` Is a blocking method.  Look into the image loading methods of the [`Toolkit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) class (which are asynchronous), or load them lazily (as they come into the view area).

Comment: *"i think that there are some high level optmizations that can be made before profiling."*  Sure, but people like @RomanC and myself likewise know that when someone goes to 'optimize' code, they usually optimize the wrong part.  A profiler will identify exactly which part of the code is the bottleneck.

Comment: i am pretty sure it is in the addImageToTray(File fname) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageIO.read()` itself is pretty slow compared to native implementation(in c++) of image reader. However when you are resizing your image using the following code:

```
AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(width/img.getWidth(), (height/img.getHeight()))); 
        img = new AffineTransformOp(af, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR).filter(img, null);
```

Which is slow and the scaled quality is very poor. Please go through this article [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) to learn about the various techniques to scaling image and their performance issue. The quick solution for fast scaling with better performance would be using the following code:

```
private static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
                    getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }    

BufferedImage tmpImage = getGraphicsConfiguration().create(newWidth, newHeight, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)tmpImage.getGraphics();
          g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
          g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
```

`tmpImage` is now the new scaled image. The performance is better. There are known library in pure java which will give higher quality scaled image in optimal time cost:

1. [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)
2. [java-image-scaling](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/wiki/Introduction)